# Encountering issues with Docker on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine, devops

I am trying to run docker on my machine but I am getting
`update failed: wsl.exe –update n–web-download not supported`

So far I did enable Windows Virtual Machine, Windows subsystem for Linux and Hypervisor platform
I have installed the newest version of WSL and when I check from terminal I do get that I have the WSL verion 2, I have also installed Ubuntu 20.04 and still I get the same error